# What format/codec is used by Windows Live (MSN) Messenger's voice clips?

Tags: windows-live-messenger, instant-messaging, windows-live

What format/codec is used by Windows Live Messenger/MSN Messenger's voice clips?

VLC doesn't recognize them, I'm trying to get them to play on my Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Live Messenger uses [the proprietary Siren 7 codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren_(codec)).